# Vsts Build for Xamarin Android fails

Tags: android, xamarin, tfs, azure-pipelines

I receive on my hosted (Hosted VS2017) VSTS Build the following error:

```
COMPILETODALVIK(0,0): Error :
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=COMPILETODALVIK;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=;]
COMPILETODALVIK : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL error :  [d:\a\1\s\src\Android\Android.csproj]
  Exception in thread "main" 
  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

The build locally works without errors.

Comment: Have you seen this forum post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21744/urgent-xamarin-forms-maps-does-not-build-compiletodalvik-unexpected-top-level ?

Comment: no changing the Java Max Heap Size to 1G doens't change this problem

Comment: maybe @starain-MSFT has a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Milen to add the link.
Increasing the Java Max Heap Size to 1G in my project solves the problem. You will found this configuration in your project properties under Android Options and the click the button Advanced.

#### ATTENTION: Do this in the build configuration where you need it. I added it to both Debug and Release.